# Angular 2 - jQuery Masonry not loading as it has to wait for get request

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

Ive built and API with Laravel, my controller makes a call to twitter, and instagram to get my latest posts.. this is relatively slow taking about 2 second to complete and feed back to the page.. I am using jQuery masonry to display these items using angulars ngFor - This is all great however I have the masonry initialized on page load and at that time it has to wait for the posts to be pulled in, currently im using a timeout function which works but its not that elegant or reliable, is there any way i can keep track of when the ngFor has finished loading the results then initialize the masonry plugin simultaneously

the service

```
        public getSocialMedia() {

            this._http.get(this.apiUrl).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(data => {
               // console.log( data.socialwall );
              this._dataStore.socialwall = data.socialwall;

                //console.log(this._SocialObserver);

                this._SocialObserver.next(this._dataStore.socialwall);

            }, error => console.log('Could not load socialwall.'));

        }
```

the component

```
ngOnInit() {

            var container = jQuery('#masonry');


            setTimeout(function() { 
                container.masonry({
                    columnWidth: 5,
                    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                    isFitWidth: true,
                    isAnimated: true,
                    gutter: 15,
                    animationOptions: {
                        duration: 300,
                        queue: false
                    }
                })
                console.log('sdf');
             }, 5000);
```

the template

```
         <ul  class="list-reset social-wall-container" id="masonry">
            <li *ngFor="#social of socialwall | async" [outerHTML]="social.tile_content" (complete)="onCompletingTodo()"></li>
         </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize the container within the callback of subscription against `SocialObservable`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.this._SocialObservable.subscribe(() => {
    container.masonry({
                columnWidth: 5,
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                isFitWidth: true,
                isAnimated: true,
                gutter: 15,
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 300,
                    queue: false
                }
            })
  });
}
```

I suppose that `SocialObservable` is the observable where the `SocialObserver` comes from...

This way when `this._SocialObserver.next(this._dataStore.socialwall);` is executed, `container.masonry(...)` will be called.

Comment: Excellent man, had to wrap it in a 1/2 a second timer but definitely cleaner solution..

Comment: me too!, but this is acceptable, because it covers the time angular ngFor finishes loading the heights, it shouldn't get over 1/2 second.